# What is the Sutra where The Buddha says that he has taught only a fraction of what he knew

Tags: reference-request, sutras

I read somewhere (don't remember where) that the Buddha mentioned, that he has taught only a fraction of what he could discern with his eye of wisdom (about existence). Does anyone know which Sutra describes this?

Comment: My question is identical to the one you have linked. Although not sure if I should delete this one, or just leave it as is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sutta (or, at least, one of those suttas) is sometimes summarized as "a handful of leaves".

[Simsapa Sutta: The Simsapa Leaves](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn56/sn56.031.than.html)

> "In the same way, monks, those things that I have known with direct knowledge but have not taught are far more numerous [than what I have taught]. And why haven't I taught them? Because they are not connected with the goal, etc.